# Magento 1.9 - Use backorder stock instead of actual stock for certain products

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

For some "**Special**" products in a webshop I want to use Backorder stock instead of actual stock which is available for those products but not sure how to proceed with it.

I have looked into `MAGE_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM` and its functions `CheckQty()` and `VerifyQty()` but still do not how shall I tell Magento to not use actual stock when I place order for those products. Because I do not want Magento to reduce the stock for them. Also I am not sure if I do it in an **event** or by overriding `MAGE_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM` class.

I be very grateful if someone can give me ideas or share some code regarding this.

No, I have not written any code so far as I am not sure how to proceed with it.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind not wanting to decrease existing stock? Would changing the 'Manage Stock' flag to "No" be satisfactory here?

Comment: Because it is a requirement to not decrease the quantity for those products @1000Nettles

Comment: What's the context, though? Do you need to maintain an actual inventory count for those products?

Comment: Context is those products have a status of Pre-orders and they need to keep the actual stock values because they are for pre-ordering and we are not considering the stock at all. @1000Nettles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge was not to reduce the the product stock if Pre-order mode is selected. As same product can be both Pre and Re-order product. So to keep the stock information same for the product I have to override few function of `cataloginventory_stock_item` class.

The functions which I override are:
`verifyStock`
`subtractQty`
`verifyNotification`

On the other hand one can look into `registerProductsSale` function who subtracts product quantity from stock.

Or can use `subtractQuoteInventory` function of an observer which according to Magento **Also called after every successful order placement to ensure subtraction of inventory**

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to not write any additional code that changes Magento's inventory behaviour as this is possible using vanilla Magento features. As you are not considering stock at all for your preorders, you can

1. Set all of the desired quantities first on the preorder products.
2. In 'Catalog > Manage Products', select all of the preorder products and click 'Actions > Update Attributes'
3. In the 'Inventory' tab, set all of these products to 'Manage Stock' being "No" by checking the 'Change' checkbox and unchecking the 'Use Config Settings' checkbox.

This will prevent all orders to not affect stock whatsoever for preorder items. You could also set the individual quantities *after* your preorder season is complete when you set the 'Manage Stock' flag back to "Yes".